# Rectify miss formatting of text in mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is that I have column where a large data dump has been slightly miss-formatted.

```
VolumeNumber
------------
Volume 1Numbers 1 & 2
Volume 1Numbers 1 & 2
Volume XIINumbers 3 & 4
Volume XIINumbers 3 & 3
```

The problem is that there is a space missing before the word Number. i.e (Volume 1 Numbers 1 & 2)

There are far to many rows for me to rectify this problem manually.

Comment: So I guess you need a space? As it seems like you forgot to ask the question..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did mention it below the code block. Sorry it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "Numbers" only appears once in `VolumeNumber`, something like this should do it:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET
    VolumeNumber = REPLACE(VolumeNumber, 'Numbers ', ' Numbers ')
WHERE
    VolumeNumber NOT LIKE '% Numbers%'
```

Comment: I was just about the ask the question of replacing instances of ` Number` where a space already exists. I'm no SQL expert but at first glance this looks like the perfect answer.

Comment: 2078 rows affected. Thanks. I will accept your answer when the lock is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to @Sean's (probably better) solution, just because I wrote it anyway :)

```
UPDATE Table1 SET VolumeNumber = 
  INSERT(VolumeNumber, LOCATE('Numbers ', VolumeNumber), 0, ' ')
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/956ee6/1).